# Index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation and include will not solve issue

Tags: angular, typescript

When including `@fireflysemantics/slice` in an Angular project I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@fireflysemantics/slice/index.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /home/ole/Temp/fstest/node_modules/@fireflysemantics/slice/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

I tried including `index.ts` like this in an `include` block:

```
  "include": ["./node_modules/@fireflysemantics/slice/index.ts"],
```

However, I still get the same error. I posted the reproduction of it in this [Angular bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16386).

Comment: Is that `index.ts` physically present in that folder?

Comment: Yes it is - But it looks like Angular no longer allows it.  However the log message asks for it ... so it's a bit confusing.  I removed it in version 9.0.7 of the library.

Answer (score 1):

It's mistake by developer of `@fireflysemantics/slice`, as developer is including `ts` files in the library, this is not standard understandable by Angualr hence the error

> Error: C:\Users\demo\Documents\angular\demong\node_modules@fireflysemantics\slice\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
>   The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library.

Until the developer makes the changes in the library, you need to **remove** `index.ts` file from `node_modules\@fireflysemantics\slice`.

After removing `index.ts`, angular will use valid `index.js` from same directory.

After removing the `index.ts` file, `ng serve` again, it should work.

Also until developer fixes it, you can add following in `package.json` to start your application by `npm start`. It'll take care of the file.

```js
"start": "rm -f \"node_modules/@fireflysemantics/sliceng/index.ts\" && ng serve",
```

Comment: You can also downgrade to `v9.0.1` of the library.

Comment: I am suggesting this because, I has similar issue once and I am using features of newer library. So downgrading was not option for me. Hence I prefer this if one's using newer features and don't want to break things. :)

Comment: Hi @Plochie - I'm the developer of the library.  The library has been working fine with prior versions of Angular.  I tried upgrading it to the Angular Package Format, but then I ran into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221867/angular-build-results-in-error-cannot-call-a-namespace-v1

Comment: So I ended up reverting it.  Now it's back to the `index.ts` issue, which has never been an issue before ... and Angular is asking for it to be included  ... not excluded ...

Comment: Have u tried my solution. Im saying remove that file and keep just index.js also dont include anything anywhere. Not required.

Answer (score 0):

As I've sent a [reply](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16386#issuecomment-562922208) to the issue that you've posted on the Angular CLI repository, I'll just post a TL;DR version of the reply:

The issue is caused by a broken compilation, resulting in a format not aligned with the [Angular Package Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview) and causing the error that you're facing.

As such, I suggest that you either post a new issue to the library author regarding this concern, or you downgrade your local installation of the library to `v9.0.1` or below.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi - Initially when I got this error, I tried creating an Angular Package Format package for the library.  That's why you see the version 9XX now.  However when I did that I ran into this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221867/angular-build-results-in-error-cannot-call-a-namespace-v1

Comment: That's not an issue outside of the Angular Package Format branch I created, so I reverted back to the previous library.  Having .ts files in the library has not been a problem before.  Also the error says that the `index.ts` file needs to be  included in `tsconfig.json` so in order to include it, it must be in the package right?